# Reversing order of colorbrewer palette while using statebins package

Tags: r, ggplot2, palette, colorbrewer

```
statebins( dataset ,state_col= "state", value_col="value",
      brewer_pal = "Spectral",)
```

I'm using `statebins` package to plot energy consumption of 50 states of US. Though `Spectral` palette from colorbrewer look well on the plot:

this is in the exact opposite order I wanted them to be. How can I reverse the order of Spectral colors. In the ggplot I used to use brewerpal reversed order as:

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(20,'Spectral')))
```

But when I am using `Spectral` the other way like in the first code chunk, I am not able to use the reverse order.

Details about Statebins package: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/statebins/

The function I am using here is statebins (which Creates a new ggplot-based "statebin" chart for USA states ,discrete scale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line of the source code for `statebins()` that sets the color palette in a `ggplot` layer:

```
gg <- gg + scale_fill_brewer(palette = brewer_pal, name = legend_title)
```

It calls `scale_fill_brewer()`, without allowing you to modify the `direction` argument.  This means `brewer_pal` in `statebins()` has to be set to a valid `palette` argument for `scale_fill_brewer()`, and that's the extent of customization you're allowed. You can't pass a reversed palette, you just have to pick an existing one, either by name or number.